# Accessing glTF animation extras property

Tags: three.js

The [glTF 2.0 spec for animation](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#animation) includes the "extras" property for Application-specific data. Currently I can't find the extras property on animations being surfaced anywhere in three.js. Would it make sense to update the AnimationClip class in three.js to have a userData property, similar to the Material class, and to copy the Animation extras to this property during glTF loading? Or did I miss it and it is already being copied into an object that I just didn't see?

Comment: three.js does not have a .userData property on the AnimationClip object, so THREE.GLTFLoader does not do anything with "extras" properties on these objects. I think your best bet would be to submit a pull request or an issue to the three.js repository (github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) with an example model to test for this case.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into submitting a pull request.